# Debug for javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC application, and would like some code in JavaScript to run only if I am in debug mode.  I do not want that code to run when I release the code.

In other words, is there anything similar to the following code in C#, for javascript / jQuery?

```
#if (DEBUG)
  // debugging code block here
#else
  // release code block here
#endif
```

Comment: `following code in C# for javascript` `some code in javascript` Which language?! Above snippet looks fine...

Comment: Just create a global called DEBUG, but you should really remove all debugging code on a production site, so I don't see the point ?

Comment: the way my application is designed, I use a different set of variables when debugging than in production. so I do need this kind of a functionality for my application..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Here is the JavaScript version.

```
var DEBUG = true;

if(DEBUG) {
    // debug code
} else {
    // production code
}
```

Comment: oh, I wanted to know if I can use the variable from the visual studio compiler. Basically, I can compile code from visual studio, under Debug mode, or release mode ...

Comment: I ended up using this kind of a solution for this scenario, so I am going to mark this as answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using the construct in your question and setting something in your viewmodel to include/exclude the javascript.

```
public ActionResult XXX()
{
    var vm=new MyViewModel(); //or just use ViewBag/ViewData
#if (DEBUG)
    vm.RunJS=true;
#else
    vm.RunJS=false;
#endif
    return View(vm);
}
```

then in your view

```
@if(Model.RunJS)
{
    <script ...></script>
}
```

or use a similar construct to pass the DEBUG status through to your javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    startMyJavascript(@Model.IsDebug?"true":"false");
</script>
```

(not so sure about Razor syntax, but I think the above is good)

Comment: +1, debug code in JavaScript is submitted regardless if it's required/not. If you can stop the code directly from the back-end that would be the best option.

Comment: I want to run parts of the code in the JS file, depending upon the debug state. I don't want to include / exclude files ...

Comment: @TK1: Javascript running in the browser has no awareness of the DEBUG (or otherwise) status of your backend. You need to pass it through the View as I suggest above.

Comment: @TK1 this isn't including files.. in ASP.NET when you do this: `if(1 == 2)alert("hey") else alert("hi")` the javascript received by the browser is: `alert("hi")`

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the ViewBag along with @Html.Raw(). I do this occasionally and it works well.

Controller:

```
#if DEBUG
    ViewBag.JavaScript = "String representation of JS code";
#endif
    return View();
```

View:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.JavaScript)
```

I would also recommend using an include such as

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

rather than the raw JavaScript to avoid having to put all of that mess in your controller.